# Change text inside a button in prototype

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have a button with class 'scalable' inside a div with id 'product_form', i want to change the text of the span within that button, i have the following jQuery script to get what i want.

```
<form id='product_form'>
    <button class='scalable' name='submit'>
        <span>old Text</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

I want to change the text 'old text' in the button to 'new text' inside the span within the button using the form id and i want to do the same using prototype.

Here is the jQuery equivalent code:

```
jQuery('#product_form button.scalable span').text('new text');
```

But i don't have jQuery and i wanna perform the same task in prototype.

please suggest me the equivalent code for the above in prototype.

Thanks.

Comment: mm can you explain your question more ??

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya i have added more explanation to my questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CSS selectors use [`$$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) which returns an [`Array`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/). One way to proceed is to assume only the [first](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/prototype/first/) element.

```
$$('#product_form button.scalable span').first().update('new text');
```

Alternatively, you can affect all items in the array.

```
$$('#product_form button.scalable span').invoke('update', 'new text');
```

Comment: The `.update(x)` is equal with `.innerHTML = x` in Prototype. So this will not escape, not like the `.text()` of jquery! - http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/update/